# Hex to signed Decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a log file named log1 with hex values in the format below:

```
D8  D4  D4  D2        
D6  D4  D4  D2  
D6  D4  D4  D2    
D6  D4  D4  D1  
...............etc
```

how can i convert this values to signed decimal ( see format below) and then save them to another file named log2?

```
-40 -44 -44 -46   
-42 -44 -44 -46   
-42 -44 -44 -46   
-42 -44 -44 -47    
....................etc



    with open("log1.log","r") as f:
         data = f.read()
    def s16(value):
        return -(value & 0x80) | (value & 0x7f)
   new_data = s16(int(data[0:2], 16)), s16(int(data[3:5], 16)), s16(int(data[6:8], 16)), s16(int(data[9:11], 16))

    with open("log2.log","w") as f:
         f.write(new_data)
```

That's what I have so far, with this code i am able to print the first line

```
(-40, -44, -44, -46)
```

but I am not sure how to make it print all the lines and not just the first line Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are two's complement bytes:

```
return value - 256 if value > 127 else value
```

Comment: Nice, simple and understandable. Better than using bit operators.